# How to point the website to a particular Folder in IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, web, asp.net-mvc-5

I am a beginner in web development. I am not sure how to tell the website to point to a particular folder in IIS. I have ASP.Net MVC - 5 Web Application.

Step 1. Bought a domain/url.

Step 2. Bought a server with IP Address (Windows Server).

Step 3. Pointed the url to the Server's IP Address..

Step 4. Have locally published my webapp code from visual studio. And now I need to paste this code on the server.

**Question 1.** Now where do I need to put the code in server so that the IIS will host it and anyone visiting that website will hit that folder which has all my website code. I am a beginner please guide me.

**Question 2.** In future I will put another web site code too on that same server, let's say the URL for new web app is xyz.com. How to tell xyz.com to go to the other folder dedicated for it, and not the older one. Basically, How multiple web site hosting will work?

PS: using remote desktop client. I am able to log in to my windows server.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What if I don't want to create a publish profile. I want to copy paste the code directly in server.

Comment: You need to define the bindings for your website. Select the website and right click and select EditBindings... and add the DNS name and port no. where the website would be accessed.

Answer (score 5):

In IIS, by default one site is created which points to `"%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot"` and it has a default HTTP binding where it listens to all incoming requests on **`PORT 80`**.

Now in your scenario, you have several options. You can either create a new site and point it to the folder where your published code resides or you can edit the existing site configuration to point to the folder where your app resides. Below instruction is to edit the exiting site configuration:

- Launch IIS Manager
- Right click the **Default Web Site** and navigate to **Manage Website** > **Advanced Settings**
- Under Default settings, update the **physical path** to point to the folder where the app resides.[image]

> NOTE: you will have to give permissions to **IIS_IUSRS** account on
>   the folder or run the application pool under the context of a user
>   which has necessary privileges to read from the directory.

FYI, all the IIS configuration resides in **`applicationhost.config`** file which resides in `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv` folder.

Inside this file, the site configuration is present under the **`<sites>`** xml tag. 
Here is an exmaple:

```
<sites>
    <site name="Default Web Site" id="1">
        <application path="/">
            <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot" />
        </application>
        <bindings>
            <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:" />
        </bindings>
    </site>
</sites>
```

I wouldn't recommend editing the file directly as it can be prone to human errors. I would recommend to use **[appcmd](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772200(v=ws.10).aspx)** commandline utility instead.

You can leave the binding as it is. As per the above binding, all the requests that hits port 80 on the server will be handled by the web app. If you intend to add **HTTPS** support, then you will have to purchase a SSL certificate and then add a SSL Binding for your site.

Answer (score 0):

The website usually goes in the `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` folder. That is the default IIS root directory. You can change this if you please in the IIS settings mentioned below.

For the second website, you can add another folder anywhere on the server, technically. In IIS: Right-click `Sites` -> `Add Web Site` and then set the physical path and other details to your new site's file directory.

Edit: I missed the DNS part. You just have to point the DNS name through your hosting company to the IP and port of your website. For the second site, just put it through a different port and point to the same IP and that port. There's other ways to do it, however: [Multiple domains on same webserver](https://forums.iis.net/t/1190202.aspx?host%20multiple%20website%20on%20single%20webserver%20)